# Как отнять UTCTIme от UTCTime и получить разницу в днях?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Н:р:// 
Я хочу отнять от UTCTime - UTCTime.
Я нашел вот такую функцию:

`diffUTCTime :: UTCTime -> UTCTime -> NominalDiffTime`

Но я получаю разницу в `NominalDiffTime`,а мне нужно получать разницу в днях

Есть какая-то функция для этого?

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю, `nominalDiffTimeToSeconds :: NominalDiffTime -> Pico` дает количество секунд в `NominalDiffTime`, которое потом можно будет разделить на 60*60*24, чтобы получить количество дней.

**UPD**. Лучший вариант, похоже, просто разделить на `nominalDay :: NominalDiffTime` и сконвертировать во что надо с помощью `fromRational . toRational`.